# Dataweave 2.0 - XML to JSON Array: grouping by id across different XML structures

Tags: json, xml, transformation, dataweave, mulesoft

I am trying to achieve something like Data Structure B, from Data Structure A.

Not sure how to loop over the XML structure and then group results by <ORDER_NUMBER> and also extracting the root element i.e <TYPE_A> as "type" and  as "message".

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Note: Empty elements are expected i.e <TYPE_B/>

Thanks

Structure A:

```
<root>
   <TYPE_A>
      <row id="0">
         <MESSAGE>Unique Message</MESSAGE>
         <ORDER_NUMBER>123</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </row>
   </TYPE_A>
   <TYPE_B/>
   <TYPE_C>
      <row id="0">
         <MESSAGE>Unique Message</MESSAGE>
         <ORDER_NUMBER>123</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </row>
      <row id="1">
         <MESSAGE>Unique Message</MESSAGE>
         <ORDER_NUMBER>789</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </row>
      <row id="2">
         <MESSAGE>Unique Message</MESSAGE>
         <ORDER_NUMBER>555</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </row>
   </TYPE_C>
   <TYPE_D>
      <row id="0">
         <MESSAGE>Unique Message</MESSAGE>
         <ORDER_NUMBER>555</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </row>
      <row id="1">
         <MESSAGE>Unique Message</MESSAGE>
         <ORDER_NUMBER>123</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </row>
      <row id="2">
         <MESSAGE>Unique Message</MESSAGE>
         <ORDER_NUMBER>789</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </row>
   </TYPE_D>
</root>
```

Structure B:

```
[  
  {
    "orderNumber": "123",
    "type": "A",
    "message": "Unique Message"
  },
  {
    "orderNumber": "123",
    "type": "C",
    "message": "Unique Message"
  },
  {
    "orderNumber": "789",
    "type": "C",
    "message": "Unique Message"
  },
  {
    "orderNumber": "555",
    "type": "C",
    "message": "Unique Message"
  },
  {
    "orderNumber": "555",
    "type": "D",
    "message": "Unique Message"
  },
  {
    "orderNumber": "123",
    "type": "D",
    "message": "Unique Message"
  },
  {
    "orderNumber": "789",
    "type": "D",
    "message": "Unique Message"
  }
]
```

Comment: It will take a long way if you properly indent your sample data.  Moreover, your output sample data seem incomplete.  I see three `TYPE_C`s and three `TYPE_D`s in the input but only two and one in the corresponding output.  Please fix your sample data so the element of guessing is eliminated ;).

Comment: My apologies, I was a bit rushed when I asked the original question. I updated, thanks!

Comment: Please accept an answer if your question was answered.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dynamic solution. Filter out null objects first (TYPE_B in this case), grab the keys of the root object and map through them. For each type, grab the `valuesOf` the corresponding object in `rootData` which will return an array of those objects. Finally map through that collection and and perform your transformation.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var rootData = payload.root filterObject not isEmpty($)
---
keysOf(rootData) flatMap ((messageType, index) -> 
    valuesOf(rootData[messageType]) map ((order) -> 
        {
            orderNumber: order."ORDER_NUMBER",
            "type": upper(messageType[-1]),
            message: order."MESSAGE"
        }
    )      
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for you but only if you know all the types

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---

orders: (if (payload.root.TYPE_A != null) 
    (payload.root.*TYPE_A map (object, index) -> {
    orderNumber: object.row.ORDER_NUMBER,
    "type": "A",
    message: object.row.MESSAGE
}) else ([])) ++
(if (payload.root.TYPE_B != null) 
    (payload.root.*TYPE_B map (objectB, indexB) -> {
    orderNumber: objectB.row.ORDER_NUMBER,
    "type": "B",
    message: objectB.row.MESSAGE
}
) else ([])) ++
(if (payload.root.TYPE_C != null) 
    (payload.root.*TYPE_C map (objectC, indexC) -> {
    orderNumber: objectC.row.ORDER_NUMBER,
    "type": "C",
    message: objectC.row.MESSAGE
}
) else ([]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, makes sense. I appeared to have to make a very small amendment in order to get each child of each TYPE element, see below:

if (payload.root.TYPE_C != null) 
    (payload.root.TYPE_C.*row map (objectC, index) -> {
    orderNumber: objectC.ORDER_NUMBER,
    "type": "C",
    message: objectC.MESSAGE
}) else ([])

Comment: You could at minimum create a function to do this and pass the TYPE_# you're looking for into the function instead of repeating it for every order. This is very redundant

Answer (score 0):

Here's another "dynamic" solution, pick the one that performs the best and use it:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var xml = '<root>
    <TYPE_A>
      <row id="0">
        <MESSAGE>Unique Message</MESSAGE>
        <ORDER_NUMBER>123</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </row>
    </TYPE_A>
    <EMPTY_TYPE_B/>
    <TYPE_C>
      <row id="0">
        <MESSAGE>Unique Message</MESSAGE>
        <ORDER_NUMBER>123</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </row>
      <row id="1">
        <MESSAGE>Unique Message</MESSAGE>
        <ORDER_NUMBER>789</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </row>
      <row id="2">
        <MESSAGE>Unique Message</MESSAGE>
        <ORDER_NUMBER>555</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </row>
    </TYPE_C>
    <TYPE_D>
      <row id="0">
        <MESSAGE>Unique Message</MESSAGE>
        <ORDER_NUMBER>555</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </row>
      <row id="1">
        <MESSAGE>Unique Message</MESSAGE>
        <ORDER_NUMBER>123</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </row>
      <row id="2">
        <MESSAGE>Unique Message</MESSAGE>
        <ORDER_NUMBER>789</ORDER_NUMBER>
      </row>
    </TYPE_D>
</root>'

var data = read(xml,"application/xml")
---
orders: data.root filterObject (not isEmpty($)) 
mapObject do {
    var tp = ($$ as String splitBy "_")[-1]
    var rs = $.*row
    ---
    (tp): rs map (r) -> {
        orderNumber: r.ORDER_NUMBER,
        "type": tp,
        message: r.MESSAGE
    }
}
pluck $
reduce (e,acc=[]) -> acc ++ e
```

Comment: Do you have something against the word Dynamic? lol

Comment: Lol nope, I would have used flexible but since I saw your response I choose to be consistent ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another dynamic solution

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"

fun mapRows(key, rows) =
    rows map
        {
            "type": key[-1],
            "orderNumber":$.ORDER_NUMBER,
            "message": $.MESSAGE
        }

---

flatten(payload.root pluck mapRows($$, $.*row))
```